# Crop mp3 file with ffmpeg which contains album cover

Tags: ffmpeg

For cropping mp3 to 30 seconds i use this and it worked well until somebody uploaded mp3 file with album cover

```
ffmpeg -t 30 -i in.mp3 -acodec copy out.mp3
```

And now i've got this:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your ffmpeg build does not have the PNG encoder.

Use

```
ffmpeg -t 30 -i in.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp3
```